# How to create No of Virtual machines in Azure through ARM template in East US region?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I would like to know how to create No of Virtual machines or 20 Virtual machines in Azure through ARM template in East US region.I know how to create one Virtual machine though ARM template but don't know how to create 20 VM's in a single ARM template.Also I would like to know how to enable monitoring and want to add storage account in this same template. I am new to Azure Infra side and Learnt some things in azure but need your help in this. Appreciate your quick help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a better way using Azure Devops Pipelines :

1. Check if your organisation have already a dev.azure.com account (Azure Devops), otherwise, you can still use the free/dev version..
2. Create an azure repository or github Repos where to put your ARM template.
3. Configure your release pipeline with an ARM Deploy task.
4. You can organize the 20 deployments you have into stages, and configure them to run the way you want!
5. You could customise each deployment depending on your inputs (VM's name, Vnet's name, Stroage Account's name, SKU, VM's size, OS type, ...)

Check Azure Devops online documentation - How to deploy ARM template with Azure pipelines.